# Show that a interval from a boolean algebra is also a boolean algebra and that a function is surjective

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

We have an boolean algebra $(B,\lor, \land, ', 0, 1)$ and $b \in B - \{0\}$.

We consider $[0,b] = \{x \in B | 0\le x\le b \} \subset B$, where $\le$ means an order relationship introduced in the lattice $(B, \lor, \land)$

I have to show that :

$(B_b, \lor_b, \land_b, *, 0, b)$ it's also an boolean algebra (they are noted with $_b$ because they are restrictions in the $[0,b]$ interval).

The function $f_b:B \to B_b, f_b(x) = b\land x, \forall x \in B$ is an surjective function.

I mention that I have no experience working with boolean algebra, I'm just studying from a book, I read the theory, but do not know how to aproach the exercises.
Any help would be very appreciated...

Thank you !

Comment: It's better to include the definition of a Boolean algebra from your book. To prove the first proposition you should check that the structure $(B_b, \vee_b, \wedge_b, *, 0, b)$ satisfies this definition. Check each of the axioms from defenition separately and tell us where you got stuck. To prove the second one you should do pretty much the same thing: write down the definition of surjective function and use the following: $b \wedge x = x, \forall x \in B_b$ by the definition of the interval $[0, b].$

Comment: Thank you, I'll do so ! :D

Answer (score 1):

The interval $[0,b]$ is a sublattice and so it is distributive. Every interval in a complemented modular lattice  is complemented. $[0,b]$ is a distributive complemented lattice. What is a [Boolean lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure))?